# PHP reading csv column into array

Tags: php

I there a php function that enables me to read a csv column (COLUMN NOT LINE) into an array or a string ?

thank you in advance.

Comment: Read the line then keep only the column you are interested in? Also, "into an array or a string" does not make sense. Arrays and strings represent different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May this will help.
http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.fgetcsv.php
Just grab the position of the row for the column you want to have.

Answer (score 12):

```
$csv = array_map("str_getcsv", file("data.csv")); 
$header = array_shift($csv); 
// Seperate the header from data

$col = array_search("Value", $header, true); 
 foreach ($csv as $row) {      
 $array[] = $row[$col]; 
}
```

Comment: keep in mind that if you use something that's not in your file as the first argument in `array_search`, you'll still get the first 'column'

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr=array();
$row = -1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);

        $row++;
        for ($c = 0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            $arr[$row][$c]= $data[$c];
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should give `fgetcsv` method a try. It lets you read a file line by line and returns associative array. This function is specially for reading from CSV files.

In any case you will have to read each line even if you will have to process just a column.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php