# Passing array into in_array()

Tags: php, arrays

Please consider the following PHP:

```
function get_ship_class()
{
    $csv = array_map("str_getcsv", file("somefile.csv", "r")); 
    $header = array_shift($csv); 

    // Seperate the header from data
    $col = array_search("heavy_shipping_class", $header); 

    foreach ($csv as $row)
    {      
        $array[] = $row[$col]; 
    }
}
```

How do I pass the resulting array from the above function into

```
if( in_array() ){
    //code
}
```

?

Comment: You have to return it, then pass the function call into it

Comment: in function you can use return $array; and the when you call get_ship_class() function you can retrieve your array

Comment: where did $array come from ?

Comment: @Andrew the function was borrowed from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17653946/php-reading-csv-column-into-array) answer.  Is it incorrect?

Comment: add `return $array;` after closing `}` for the foreach loop in function and use like `if (in_array('needle', get_ship_class()) {}`

Comment: @ptrcao I'm on mobile right now, seems like you've got a solid answer below :-)

Answer (score 7):

A slightly abbreviated version, but the same as is being suggested is to return the required data from the function but using `array_column()` to extract the data...

```
function get_ship_class()
{
    $csv = array_map("str_getcsv", file("somefile.csv", "r")); 
    $header = array_shift($csv); 

    // Seperate the header from data
    $col = array_search("heavy_shipping_class", $header); 

    // Pass the extracted column back to calling method
    return array_column($csv,$col);
}
```

And to use it...

```
if ( in_array( "somevalue", get_ship_class() )) {
   //Process 
}
```

If you are going to use this returned value a few times, it may be worth storing it in a variable rather than passing it straight into the `in_array()` method.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer that the comments are suggesting.

```
function get_ship_class(){
    $array = array();
    $csv = array_map("str_getcsv", file("somefile.csv", "r")); 
    $header = array_shift($csv); 
    // Seperate the header from data    
    $col = array_search("heavy_shipping_class", $header); 
    foreach ($csv as $row) {      
    array_push($array, $row[$col]);
    // array_push($array, "$row[$col]"); // You may need it as a string instead.
    }
return $array;
}



if( in_array("whatever_you_are_looking_for", get_ship_class()) ){
//code
}
```